# Flutter - OneSignal Notification not receiving on iOS 17

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, onesignal

I updated my iPhone 14 from iOS 16 to iOS 17
I sent two notifications and I did not receive them on the phone notification bar.
I’m not :100:  percent sure this is the cause but it was working until I updated to the latest iOS

there is 2 warning on my one signal project.
[image]

Comment: The warning seems to be pretty straightforward english. Even with a link to help you fix it. Did you try? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: but according to this warning notification should not work on any iOS device but it is working fine except for iOS 17.